# Display of multi values image field problem

Tags: views, 6, entities, media

I am getting this output for example image:

```
    <div class="field-item field-item-1">
        <a class="imagefield other-classes" rel="lightshow[field_photos][Exerci conventio quia causa quae probo. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://ita.pl/ita_drupal/sites/default/files/zdjecia/dodatkowe/filefield_c0ldK7_1.png&quot; 
  target=&quot;_blank&quot; 
  id=&quot;lightbox2-download-link-text&quot;&gt;Download Original&lt;/a&gt;]" href="http://ita.pl/ita_drupal/sites/default/files/zdjecia/dodatkowe/filefield_c0ldK7_1.png"></a></div>
```

I know it looks horrible, but main problem is that there is no [img] tag inside [a] tag.

Only first image of list render properly.

Comment: I used imagefield several times, and it workes great even in multiple value form. can you explain more?

Comment: It works for me too, but suddenly turn to broken. I am checking it know.

Answer (score 2):

I could be way off, but with the information given, your problem might because of lightshow.   Try another module such as [colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try because I am wonder if it helps. In other multi values fields lightbox works ok.

Comment: I checked colorbox and everything works ok